# In Rails can i pass additional filter options in tagged_with method for acts-as-taggable-on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on

I have an object called Course. I would like to provide tags on courses so that users can search/filter based on those tags.

I'm using the gem acts-as-taggable-on:

```
Course.tagged_with(params[:tag])
```

In this method can I pass additional filtering on Course columns/attributes i.e. `where enabled = 'Y'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `.tagged_with` should be chainable with other ActiveRecord queries:

```
Course.tagged_with(params[:tag]).where(enable: "Y")
```